# How add child to existing duiring parent saving in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, parent-child

Suppose that `Parent` already exisits with `id=1`. And it already has 2 children. How to make code:

```
 Parent parent = parentDao.getbyId(1);
 //here somebody added a collection of children 
 parent.setChildren(myNewCreatedChildren)
 parentDao.save(parent);
```

How save parent to get `parentDao.getbyId(1).getChildren()` return `somebody children + myNewCreatedChildren` after that? E.g. call `parentDao.save(parent)` should add children but do **not** override.

**Note**

The question is about situation when chidren are added outside of java code (or may be in other thread) to the `parent` after it was loaded by doa but before it saved to database.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_optimistic

Comment: Not understand you, about documentation reference. Yes a version numver or transaction managment can be used to indicate have we changes with parent or not. But question is not about that, it is about adding children to existed collection without it's loading. Could you please add some more explanation?

Comment: AFAIK, adding an element to the collection will count as a change to the parent, the version will be incremented, and the conflict will be detected.

Answer (score 0):

I guess  it should be `Collection<Children> children`,    and your code `parent.setChildren(myNewCreatedChildren)` should be replaced with `parent.getChildren().addAll(children)`;

But from my experience it is a bit easier not to deal with `@ManyToOne(mappedBy="parent")` and fetch policies at all, it is much easier to provide  `childrenDao.fetchChildrensOfParent(parent)`  and `childrenDao.storeChildren(parent, children)` methods and work with those only when it is needed , with such constructions even easier to add Caching to application and provide better control on its population and eviction.